# Correct usage of closure in for loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding an event listener to some elements I'm looping through and need a closure in order to preserve the index in the event function.

```
<button>solution 1</button>
<button>solution 2</button>

<script>
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var log = (function closure(number) {
        return function () {
            console.log(number);
        };
    })(i);

    buttons[0].addEventListener("click", log);
}
for (var i = 0, len = 3; i < len; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        var log = function () {
                console.log(i);
            };
        buttons[1].addEventListener("click", log);   
    })(i);
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paptd/11/

Both these solutions output 0, 1, 2 correctly (try 'wrong' to see what happens without a closure) but I'm trying to understand which one I should use and why.

Which way is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Instead of having hundred of listeners you could use event delegation. It would take up less memory and you would have fewer ties between code and the DOM.
You would only need one event listener. Example: http://nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The first one works because you are defining a closure, returning a function from it, then assigning that function to a listener.

The second one seems more proper, since the closure encompasses the entire loop content, making it more obvious that the value of `i` is to be "locked" there.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use any of these--you're creating *n* identical functions inside of your loop. You should refactor your code into a named function that returns the event handler:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

function createHandler(number) {
    return function () {
        console.log(number);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {   
    buttons[0].addEventListener("click", createHandler(i));
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/paptd/12/